# what is the difference between getCaName() and getName() method in CertificateAuthority class for fabric-client module?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I was reading the docs provided for [fabric-client and stumbled upon](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/CertificateAuthority.html)

Here, it states `getCaName()` method returns CA name of Certificate Authority, while `getCaName()` returns name of Certificate Authority.

What is the difference between these two? and how is Name and CA name of the Certificate Authority different from each other?
Thanks in advance

Comment: It also says that should be used in the request
`Gets the name of this CertificateAuthority to use in request`,
 Fabric-ca servers support multiple Certificate Authorities from a single server.IF you don't provide a CaName in the request then the default CA is the target of request.

Comment: @I.g.Karolos well i also thought that  this statement differentiates them a little  that's why my other question was difference between name and CAName? how are they different? will there be any difference in the output for getCaName() and getName()?  that's the thing i want to know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are intended for different purposes.  It also looks the the docs for the [constructor](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/CertificateAuthority.html#CertificateAuthority__anchor) do not show the optional parameters (which include `caname` as well as `name`).

`getName()` returns the value of the `name` parameter passed into the constructor and is basically just any name you want to give to the CA in order to identify it.

`getCaName()` returns the value of the `caname` parameter passed into the constructor and should match the `ca.name` property which is set when running multiple CA instances within the same fabric-ca process.